# VIM: Run current file in IPython and remain open

Tags: vim, ipython

I can run a file with :! ipython %, but it will close when the script is finished. How can I run the current script in IPython, and make it remain open? Currently I am hitting :! ipython and then %load the current file by name, but I'd like to automatize it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From within an IPython shell you can run a script with the %run magic!
Assuming you are in the right directory:
`%run script.py`
Will execute the script and leave you in an interactive prompt, where you can interact with objects from the script. Hope this helps!

Comment: And how can I do that starting from VIM? To run the current script in IPython and then remain in the REPL?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I misunderstood your question. You could try posting as an issue in the [ipython github repo](https://github.com/ipython/ipython). I have asked about installation issues there before and they seem pretty friendly and willing to help.